# Report: Incorrect Column Sum Total

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, rdl

I have created a tabular report that has a couple of drilldowns that are subtotaled at the top of each table group via the following expression

**Code:**

```
=Sum(Fields!StandardTime.Value)
```

**Data:**

```
+-------+---+------------+----+----------+
|Company|Job|StandardTime|User|ActualTime|
+-------+---+------------+----+----------+
|Wirebox|tx |  5         |Joe |  1       |
|Wirebox|tx |  5         |Theo|  3       |
|Wirebox|ty |  10        |Joe |  4       |
|Wirebox|ty |  10        |Theo|  7       |
+-------+---+------------+----+----------+
```

**Report:**

```
+-------+---+------------+----+----------+
|Company|Job|StandardTime|User|ActualTime|
+-------+---+------------+----+----------+
|Wirebox|   |   15       |    |  15      |<---Company Total
|       |tx |   5        |    |  4       |<---Job Total
|       |   |            |Joe |  1       |
|       |   |            |Theo|  3       |
|       |ty |  10        |    |  11      |<---Job Total
|       |   |            |Joe |  4       |
|       |   |            |Theo|  7       |
+-------+---+------------+----+----------+
```

The problem I am getting is when I add the StandardTime together to get the total for the company with =Sum(Fields!StandardTime.Value) the result is 30 and not the desired 15 as per my example. I am guessing the report is adding all of the StandardTime for SQL query. But that data is duplicated in the query. Is there a way to Total only the figures I am outputting in the report?

Comment: I have a feeling its to do with scope. If I could only SUM the first row of every user scope I think it will work

Answer (score 0):

Add "Company" Group  then total before on "StandardTime". for the also Add "Job" Group  then total before on "StandardTime". This will give you your desire result.

[Here a link how to add group on the report](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220470.aspx)

Here is the sample that i tested..

[image: Report defination]

Results:

[image: Report Results]

Good luck!!

Comment: It is already in a "Company" Group because when you make a drill down report with the report wizard it does all that for you

Comment: I have test the report please look snapshot above. Hope this help.

Comment: Hi would it be possible to send me a copy of your test report please

Comment: Hi @Hiten004 I am still having this issue and you said you managed to solve it. Would you be able to solve the issue for me and my company would be willing to pay for your time. Please let me know thanks.

Comment: @TheoKouzelis please check the results and varified. I have update the answer. i am not sure how to send the report file. i can not attach to the answer.

Comment: yep those results are correct. You can send it to my email if you like which is theo@wirebox.co.uk